# Split a textbox into 4 seperate ones but save in one EF field

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textbox, concatenation

The title doesn't really explain my scenario very well, so I will try to explain the best way I can.

I have recently learnt how to `multi-bind` using a `listview` to `concatenate` two `fields` and separate them with a "," which was relatively easy to achieve. But now, I want to achieve something a bit more advanced but not sure if it is quite possible to do and I am not too sure how to go about achieving it and therefore would like some help or advice or guidance to help me achieve this :).

I am using `Entity framework` to create an entity model and some of the tables are larger then I expected therefore, I do not wish to add more fields then required (which is in this case).

One of my requirements, I have a `textbox`, containing no more then 13 characters. But, I now have been asked to achieve something similar to the image below;

[image]

As you can see from the image, the `textbox` at the top is what I have currently, but I want to find a way of splitting that `textbox` like the one below (containing; 123 P A ...).

Leading back to my question, is there a way to `concatenate` a `textbox` within an application that contains a possible further 4 `textboxes` and than they all save within one `field` of an EF model to reduce the amount of fields in a table?

Is this a bit ambitious or am I over thinking the problem too much and there is a far similar way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT:

In the end, I created a separate table to achieve this. Quick and easy fix. Albeit, still an interesting question and still curious of a way of achieving it.

Answer (score 1):

I would write my own `UserControl` for that. It should be fairly simple.

Basically, you define a `Grid` or `StackPanel` and add w/e number of `TextBox`'s you need to it. Then, in code behind you define a dependency property, e.g. `Result`, which will serve as concatenation of `Text` properties of those texboxes. After that all you need to do is do some event handling: update `Result` whenever either of `TextBox.Text` properties changes and swap keyboard focus between `TextBox`'s as user fills them. When you are done, you can simply bind your view model property to `Result` porperty.